# Java Apache HttClient : ThreadSafe or not?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have to create a web service which interrogate a black box via an http request (method get).

I would like to use Apache http client, but with 4.3.1 version i have some warning about deprecated object & methods.

All example explain to use DefaultHttpClient which is ThreadSafe.
Now we have to use HttClientBuilder which is NOT ThreadSafe.

What is impact about that exactly ?
Stupid question : if i use it in a Spring MVC Controller (Singleton threadsafe), what are the consequences ?
Is a not thread safe process used in a thread safe become thread safe (lol) ?

Comment: What do you mean with "singleton threadsafe"? IMHO, spring singletons are not thread-safe by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly, what you want to do, but concurrency is all about sharing state between threads. If two threads access the same state in parallel, you might/will get problems.

Note that local variables are NOT shared, so if multiple threads invoke the same method in parallel, all of them have their own local variables:

```
public int safeAdd(int a, int b) {
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}
```

The local variables `a`, `b` and `sum` are NOT shared state! Every thread gets its own 'copy' of them! So the object is stateless!

> Stateless objects are always thread-safe!

Of course, things change if you publish you local variables:

```
int sum;

public int unsafeAdd(int a, int b) {
    sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}
```

Here, `sum` is not a local variable any more. It exists only once (per instance). If multiple threads call `unsafeAdd`, something bad/unexpected might/will happen!

This means, if you use your `HttpClientBuilder` only within your methods - no problem. But if you publish it (as in the example above), you must take care of parallel access.

(See also book "Java Concurrency in Practice": http://jcip.net/)

Answer (score 5):

The code below returns a [CloseableHttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html) which if you look is thread safe.

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to understand what thread-safe means first.

Class X being thread safe generally means that if you
have a class variable Y (of type X) and you use it from
multiple threads, this will not lead to any problems 
(e.g. because X's public methods are guarded/synchronized).

Saying for a thread/process that it's thread safe 
or not - that doesn't make much sense, it is about 
classes and objects of these classes.

When a class is not thread safe you can use
objects of this class as local variables
and not worry about thread-safety too.

That's because a local variable is not
shared across threads, each thread has
its own copy of it.

But if you use it as class variable
you can have thread safety problems.

Comment: Yeah i have some problem with threadSafe concept. Before i had some controller setted in XML with session scope. Now with Spring 3.1.1, controller are setted with annotations and are singleton - threadsafe. But if a method is a requestmapping with a responsebody, the scope is request...what are the consequences ? if i use a HttpClientBuilder which is not safe in this method, can i have some problems ?

Comment: If you use HttpClientBuilder and it is defined as a local/method variable, you cannot have problems. Otherwise (i.e. if it is defined as a member/class variable), you can. This is what I wrote above in a generalized form.